# If I only roll my object, what angular velocity value will change?

Tags: angular-velocity, gyroscopes

**Question 1**

I know this is a simple question but I just need clarification. This is an honest question so if anyone could help reorientate my brain I would appreciate.

Let say I have a body like this:
[Yaw Pitch Roll](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi33Imji9XPAhXLWxoKHd1WAckQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chrobotics.com%2Flibrary%2Funderstanding-euler-angles&psig=AFQjCNE1jTmcKDl1u1DQb-quBUJ2XKZzZw&ust=1476355565495435)

If I only try to roll, which angular velocity (X Y Z) will change? This brings me to question 2:

**Question 2**

[image: My graphs]
 LEFT is the Euler angle and RIGHT is the Gyroscope data. This is sampled from an IMU.

I am feeling like something is wrong here, it's like the Angular Velocity X and Z has been swapped. If we look only at the grey line, the Roll is probably less than 5 degrees, but the Angular Velocity Z is huge. Does this makes sense? I'm feeling like the degree/sec of my roll is plotted in Angular Velocity X.

Comment: The link is broken.   Generally it's a bad idea to use links to provide information essential to a question.    Better to put everything in the question, although that is admittedly very impractical in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the net angle change (roll, pitch, and yaw) and angular velocity which is primarily that angular velocity has dependence on time (that is, keeping track of time is essential for calculating it) while roll (or pitch and yaw) can just be calculated at regular intervals of time, where it is just the net rotates angle.
This is, I suppose, field data of a real plane and thus it will have the same angle change as shown by the graph and how early it is achieved is given by the angular velocity. So here, the angle has been achieved fairly quickly which could be because of the will of the pilot or the wind.
So a small change has been achieved really quickly.

P.S. In any case you can't validate the data acquired, because it has simply no links.